# Como usar retorno de função no Scilab ou MatLab?

Tags: matlab, return, funções

Estou fazendo um programa numérico simples.

Mas não consigo usar retorno das funções no Scilab alguém pode me ajudar?

A função tem que resolver um cálculo e em seguida retornar o valor para essa variável continuar a ser manipulada pelo programa.

A função principal é `integral()`

```
function funcao (x)
         x^2
         return F
endfunction

a=2
b=4
function integral()
    x=(a+b)/2 *0,222
    funcao(x)
    disp(F)
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

As funções no Matlab podem ter uma unica saída ou várias. Uma unica saída:

```
function y = media(x)
if ~isvector(x) %testa se é um vetor
    error('A entrada tem que ser um vetor')
end
y = sum(x)/length(x); 
end
```

Várias saídas:

```
function [m,s] = stat(x)
n = length(x);
m = sum(x)/n;
s = sqrt(sum((x-m).^2/n)); %calcular o desvio
end
```

Como usar:

```
valores = [12.7, 45.4, 98.9, 26.6, 53.1];
[ave,stdev] = stat(valores)
```

A saída seria assim:

```
ave =
   47.3400
stdev =
   29.4124
```

Seu problema seria algo deste tipo:

```
a=2
b=4

function F = integral(a,b)

    x = (a+b)/2*0.222
    F = funcao(x)

end

function y = funcao (x)

         y = x^2
end
```

Para mais informações ver a referencia [aqui](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).

Answer (score 0):

Não manjo nada de matlab, mas acho que o seu programa deveria ser assim:

```
function funcao (x)
    return x ^ 2
endfunction

a = 2
b = 4

function integral()
    x = (a + b) / 2 * 0.222
    f = funcao(x)
    disp(f)
endfunction
```